# Sharepoint 2010 build solution with UI then export as wsp template, to deploy in new environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I build up a solution using UI in Sharepoint 2010. Solution consisted in creating a new site, as subsite using Team Site Template. Then I added the following artifacts:

- Several Custom Columns
- 2 Custom content types using above columns
- Document Library using my content types above
- Several Custom Views created for above Document Library
- 1 Reuseable Workflow (this was developed with sharepoint designer 2010)
- 3 List Worklfow, using 'Three-state-workflow' template
- Customisation of site navigation (quick launch)
- Customisation of site home page
- Some security groups
- Added users to groups

Then I exported the site as wsp template, downloaded it to local drive.

I imported it in visual studio 2010, than changed the deployement method to 'Farm Solution' (not Sandboxed Solution) and packaged it.

I have to deploy to new sharepoint environment (new server), but till now there are issues in feature activation (total 5 features). the feature wich contains module elements is having issue.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Any idea how to streamline this process in order to avoid deployment issues ?

Comment: After many efforts I could deploy the wsp to new server, but Three-State workflows are having issue. They could not be started, also second configuration page is throwing an exception.
It looks like the associationdata for the workflow instance can not be fetched.
Googled... but no solution till now :-(

Comment: Can you please post the exceptions from the ULS? I did this a while back for a publishing site and had to go through the WSP and fix GUIDs.